# Emberjs array controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, arraycollection

My route is:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var blocks = this.store.find('block', {'objectId': 777});
        this.controllerFor("blocks").set('model', blocks);
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            object: this.store.find('object', params.id),
            blocks: blocks
        });
        //return this.store.find('object', params.id);
    }
});
```

My controller is:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function(e){
        alert('jere');
    }
});
```

Alert in init function works but next I get the error:

> Error while processing route: objects.bc.index Cannot read property
>   'length' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

What is the right way to get collection of models through ajax and show it in template with custom array controller?

Comment: Here is a full blown example showing how to use an ArrayController w/ vanilla (ish) ajax. The comments from @torazaburo are correct about hash vs array (model) but this should get your rolling (it's ember-cli based). https://github.com/toranb/async-kanban-board-store-example

Answer (score 1):

This code has a number of problems. First, `ArrayController` assumes that its model is an array, whereas your `model` hook is returning a hash. Second, your  `this.controllerFor("blocks").set('model', blocks)` call attempts to set the model for the controller to a promise, which is useless. You do not set the model for the controller in the `model` hook like this. You set it by **returning** the model, which is then installed (after it resolves) into the controller by your (or the default) `setupController` hook.

You should not use an `ArrayController`, which is soon to be deprecated anyway, and instead use a plain old controller. The model for this controller will be the hash returned from the `model` hook. You need to access it explicitly in the template with `{{model}}`.

So you want something like this:

```
// route.js
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var blocks = this.store.find('block', {'objectId': 777});
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            object: this.store.find('object', params.id),
            blocks: blocks
        });
    }
});

// controller.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    init: function(e) {
        alert('jere');
    }
});
```

In your templates, instead of

```
{{#each controller}}
    blockProp is {{blockProp}}
```

as you are presumably doing now, use

```
{{#each block in model.blocks}}
    blockProp is {{block.blockProp}}
{{/each}}
And objectProp is {{model.object.objectProp}}
```

Comment: `{{#each block as model.blocks}}` should be `{{#each model.blocks as |block|}}`